# List index out of range when adding an element

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm getting the `IndexError: list index out of range` and don`t understand why. I'm just adding an new element to the dynamic list:

```
 order_array = []
 for package in names_array:
      package = names_array[i]
      logInfo("NAME : " + package)
      command = vars.sdp_info_command + " -b " + package + " | grep 'Order' | awk --field-separator=:           '{print $2}'"
      tmp = []
      r_code = execute(command, output=tmp)
      if r_code != 0:
        return 1
  order_array.append(tmp[0].strip())
```

The program fails here, but not always: `order_array.append(tmp[0].strip())`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Apparrently the execute does not add anything to tmp[0]

Comment: tmp[0] has an string always, I have checked it. This is not the problem. It always fails on the 16th element out of 38 and as I said sometimes works and others not. Thanks

Comment: Please post the exact error.

Comment: You sure this is the code? `order_array.append` is outside your `for` loop and, `return` isn't valid outside a function....

Comment: Why are you assigning names_array[i] to package? During each iteration of the loop, package will contain the corresponding value of names_array. Please do tell your intention of this code. And also be clear with what you write. Avoid unnecessary lines of code. It is a bad practice.